# Why is emacs not running (set-face-attribute ...) in init.el, even though the rest of the buffer is executed?

Tags: emacs, fonts, font-faces

I've got `(set-face-attribute 'default nil :height 100)` in my init.el because I find the default font size a little too large. However, it doesn't get executed when emacs is loaded.

I don't have an `init.elc` file that's not representative updated version of my `init.el`, and I know the rest of the my `init.el` is being executed.

There are no other `(set-face-attribute ...)` sexps after it that could be overwriting it.

Going back in to my `init.el` after loading emacs and executing it myself sets the property correctly (i.e. for all buffers (but not new frames), persistently)

Comment: Although your `init.el` is not overwriting it, it could still be having no effect. Perhaps `set-face-attribute` is a per-buffer property? (This is all from memory). You could try putting the command in a hook that gets executed later.

Comment: The code is correct.  Try using only that in your init file and eliminate all other codes and packages.  If it works then (i.e., with a blank init except for the `set-face-attribute . . .`), well, then you have a conflict with something else in your other settings.  If you have already grepped for other possible `set-face-attribute`, and come up with nothing, and if you have disabled your color themes, you will need to slowly re-enable the rest of your settings until you find the conflict.  Also look for frame settings with font specifications, like `default-frame-alist`.

Answer (score 6):

After some chopping bits out of my config file, I discovered it was due to `(add-to-list 'default-frame-alist '(font . "DejaVu Sans Mono-12"))`.

The reason I'd discounted it before was because I ran `(set-face-attribute 'default nil :height 100)` at the very end of my init file.

The solution is to change the sexp that alters `default-frame-alist` to be `(add-to-list 'default-frame-alist '(font . "DejaVu Sans Mono-12") '(height . 100))`, and remove the one that alters the face-attribute directly

Comment: 1. You should accept your own answer, if it is adequate. 2. Why don't you customize `default-frame-alist` (`M-x customize-option`), instead of fiddling with it using Lisp in your init file?  It is a user option for a reason.

Comment: Because it doesn't seem to be working quite as intended yet. I hadn't come back to edit the answer yet. As for elisp, I prefer it to using customize - I think either option is valid, and I prefer the elisp approach.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old thread, but I had the same problem and managed to fix it.  I see that you did as well, but wanted to contribute my solution, as I didn't find it anywhere else.

I just added the following line to my ~/.emacs.d/init.el:

```
(add-hook 'find-file-hook (lambda () (set-face-attribute 'default nil :height 105)))
```

And it worked.  Props to alexis in the comments on OP for the suggestion.

Comment: Doesn't this lead to the wrong font size in the initial scratch buffer?